# Learning about properties of Trees

Tags: data-structures, tree, adt, treenode

I'm trying to learn about Trees and their uses. One part of my class slide said that one definition of a tree is:

The height  (maximum distance) of a tree is the maximum level among all of the nodes in the tree.

Node quit sure what that means, can anyone explain? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The height of a tree is the length of the longest downward path to a leaf from the root.